# Locked in Fullscreen. Can't exit

Tags: macbook

I am running elementary os 0.4.1 on my macbook 4.1 (2008). Always when I watch a video on fullscreen in Firefox I cant exit the fullscreen mode after a few minutes. At the beginning it is no problem. No key shortcuts are working. the only option is to shutdown the computer.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to another site in the StackExchange network

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
Launch the Terminal from keyboard: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
Use the command: `killall firefox`